# "seen from outer space"

Tags: grammar, word-choice

> **Seen** from outer space, our earth looks like a blue planet.
>
> **Seeing** from outer space, our earth looks like a blue planet.

Which is better? I find the former fine but my teacher says it is the latter.

Comment: I wonder if maybe you're confusing the word "former" with the word "latter", or if maybe your teacher is not an expert.

Comment: I mean the first sentence and the second one

Comment: You need a better teacher. **Seen** from outer space, our earth look**s** like a blue planet.

Answer (score 2):

Your first sentence is almost correct.

The color of the earth is predominately blue when viewed from a distance, and the BBC have even created a series entitled [*The Blue Planet*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Blue_Planet).

However, your sentence should perhaps read

> *(as)* Seen from outer space, our earth look**s** like a blue **marble**.

*(The)* [**Blue Marble**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Blue_Marble) is the idiomatic expression which was coined during the Apollo 17 mission and is also the name of the famous picture (see link).

> seen from outer space

is a shortened form of

> as seen from outer space
>   when seen from outer space

if you really needed to use *seeing*, your sentence could be

> To martians *seeing* from outer space, earth looks like...

Comment: Can I rewrite your example as "The earth looks like a blue marble, martians seeing from outer space" ?

Comment: "The earth looks like a blue marble, **to** martians seeing from outer space." would have the same meaning, I actually think "looking" might be a better word choice but I was reflecting your wording "The earth looks like a blue marble, **to** martians looking from outer space.".  It also depends if martians know what a marble is, that's kind of why I didn't fill in the last bit.

Comment: The OP is asking about grammar, not word choice.

Comment: @J.R. What device are you on that the pics are too big?

Comment: @Peter: It's a matter of perspective. When the images fill the entire screen, or when you have two images that each take up more space than full text of the answer itself, then the images detract from rather than enhance the answer.